# in rstudio while using multi level perceptron(mpl) i got an error that object can not find and couldn't solve this

Tags: r, r-caret

```
set.seed(123)
library(randomForest)
library(gmodels)
library(neuralnet)
library(RSNNS)
library(Rcpp)
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
setwd("C:/Users/Mitul Shah/Desktop/UCI_HAR_Dataset/UCI_HAR_Dataset")
train_data<-read.table("train/X_train.txt")
train_lables<-read.table("train/Y_train.txt")

test_data<-read.table("test/X_test.txt")
test_lables<-read.table("test/Y_test.txt")

col_names <- readLines("features.txt")
colnames(train_data)<-make.names(col_names)
colnames(test_data)<-make.names(col_names)
colnames(train_lables)<-"lable"
colnames(test_lables)<-"lable"

train_final<-cbind(train_lables,train_data)
test_final<-cbind(test_lables,test_data)
final_data<-rbind(train_final,test_final)
final_data$lable<-factor(final_data$lable)
model_mlp
```

> caret::train(lable~.,data=final_data[ttt,],method="mlp")
>   Error in '[.data.frame'(final_data, ttt, ) : object 'ttt' not found

Comment: You are referencing a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: So, what's the solution I couldn't understand

Comment: I don't know, you didn't share what your data looks like. If you run `names(final_data)`, is `ttt` among the list of variables returned?

Comment: after above code i want to run this code model_mlp<-caret::train(lable~.,data=final_data[ttt,],method="mlp")
pre_mlp<-predict(model_mlp,final_data[-ttt,])
table(model_mlp,final_data[-ttt,1])

Comment: You're not answering my question. Is there a variable called `ttt` in `final_data`?

Comment: Since my training dataset(7352 obs. of 562 variables) and the test dataset(2947 obs. of 562 variables) are big for a normal PC to process, I pick a random subset of the training dataset and do my machine learning methods on it.

Comment: in this model_mlp<-caret::train(lable~.,data=final_data[ttt,],method="mlp")
i saw this type of syntax so, what is ttt object and what is the use of it?

Comment: in my final_data there is not any ttt column

Comment: Remove `[ttt, ]` from `final_data[ttt, ]`

Comment: then it shows the error that package e1071 is required

Comment: You need to load the e1071 package.

Comment: okay it works now at this line
table(model_mlp,final_data) it shows the error that Error in order(y) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'